# Airflow Kubernetes executor , Tasks in queued state and pod says invalid image and uses local executor

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes, airflow-scheduler, airflow

**strong text**I have installed airflow in docker and using kubernetes executor unable to trigger dags. Dag runs are in queued state. KubernetesExecutor is creating pod but it says invalid image. If i describe the pod it uses local executor instead of kubernetes executor. Please help

Attaching log file for reference

```
**kubectl describe pod tablescreationschematablescreation-ecabd38a66664a33b6645a72ef056edc
Name:         swedschematablescreationschematablescreation-ecabd38a66664a33b6645a72ef056edc
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         10.73.96.181
Start Time:   Mon, 11 May 2020 18:22:15 +0530
Labels:       airflow-worker=5888feda-6aee-49c8-a94b-39cbe5758062
              airflow_version=1.10.10
              dag_id=Swed-schema-tables-creation
              execution_date=2020-05-11T12_52_09.829627_plus_00_00
              kubernetes_executor=True
              task_id=Schema_Tables_Creation
              try_number=1
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Pending
IP:           172.17.0.46
IPs:
  IP:  172.17.0.46
Containers:
  base:
    Container ID:
    Image:         :
    Image ID:
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      airflow
      run
      Swed-schema-tables-creation
      Schema_Tables_Creation
      2020-05-11T12:52:09.829627+00:00
      --local
      --pool
      default_pool
      -sd
      /root/airflow/dags/User_Creation_dag.py
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       InvalidImageName
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR:          LocalExecutor
      AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN:  postgresql://airflowkube:airflowkube@10.73.96.181:5434/airflowkube
    Mounts:
      /root/airflow/dags from airflow-dags (ro)
      /root/airflow/logs from airflow-logs (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-64cxg (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  airflow-dags:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /data/Naveen/Airflow/dags
    HostPathType:
  airflow-logs:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /data/Naveen/Airflow/Logs
    HostPathType:
  default-token-64cxg:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-64cxg
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason         Age                     From                           Message
  ----     ------         ----                    ----                           -------
  Normal   Scheduled      <unknown>               default-scheduler              Successfully assigned default/swedschematablescreationschematablescreation-ecabd38a66664a33b6645a72ef056edc to evblfnclnullnull1538
  Warning  Failed         2m15s (x12 over 4m28s)  kubelet, evblfnclnullnull1538  Error: InvalidImageName
  Warning  InspectFailed  2m (x13 over 4m28s)     kubelet, evblfnclnullnull1538  Failed to apply default image tag ":": couldn't parse image reference ":": invalid reference format**
```

Comment: Request someone to assist on this

Answer (score 4):

It looks like there is no image defined for the workers. You can set this in the `airflow.cfg`. Be sure to set these `worker_container_repository` and  `worker_container_tag`. These are null by default which results in the behaviour you're experiencing. 
A working example:

```
 AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__WORKER_CONTAINER_REPOSITORY: "apache/airflow"
 AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__WORKER_CONTAINER_TAG: "1.10.10-python3.6"
 AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__RUN_AS_USER: "50000"
```

The airflow docs have some more detailed info on the available properties: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/configurations-ref.html#kubernetes

Comment: can we give any image name to AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__WORKER_CONTAINER_REPOSITORY and any tag to AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__WORKER_CONTAINER_TAG ??

Comment: why do you need to specify the `RUN_AS_USER` config?